How to style the `PageTitleWidget` like the default page title display (when columns are undefined on a `PageListingViewSet`)?
While migrating from ModelAdmin to PageListingViewSet, I've noticed that the default style for page title column is different when defining the PageListingViewSet without columns or adding columns with a PageTitleWidget:
Default style (without columns defined)

PageTitleWidget style

Since there are often cases where we want to customize the columns for PageListingViewSets, the inconsistency in aesthetics is becoming apparent and leads to a confusing UX.
How can define "page title" columns with the same aesthetic as the default PageListingViewSet title display?
Further research
When inspecting the source code generated by the PageTitleColumn vs. that of the PageListingViewSet without columns defined, there seems to be a missing class="title" on the td that wraps the page title widget.
https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/5f158de94a8e16a7e7bea0795d0704c2ba5e2f94/wagtail/admin/ui/tables/pages.py#L7-L10
Default markup (without columns defined)
<td class="title" data-listing-page-title="">
    <div class="title-wrapper">...</div>
    <ul class="actions">...</ul>
</td>

Markup from PageTitleWidget
<td data-listing-page-title="">
    <div class="title-wrapper">...</div>
    <ul class="actions">...</ul>
</td>


It turns out that the default classname="title" isn't applied when defining PageTitleColumn instances in the columns property of PageListingViewSets. So, the solution is as follows:
PageTitleColumn(
    "title",
    label="Title",
    sort_key="title",
    # make sure to define the classname="title"
    classname="title",
),

